# How to use ng-show with a function in the controller that returns true/false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm having trouble with understanding the working of `ng-show` attribute. I'm trying to create a modal pop-up in a video,which shows when the current time of the video is 7 or 14 or 21 seconds.So I'm using ng-show="dc.timeCheck()" where 'dc' is my controller and 'timeCheck()' my function within the controller that returns 'true' and pauses the video if the time is one of the mentioned else it returns false and plays the video.
But i'm unable to make it work and I have failed to see the reason why despite of going through various docs and tutorials!

My code

HTML:

```
 <div ng-controller="divCtrl as dc">

        <div id="ui1" ng-show="dc.timeCheck()" >


            <form role="form" ng-submit="submit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h2 style="color:brown;">{{ques[x]}}</h2>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <video id="myVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
        controls preload="auto" width="640" height="340"
        poster=""data-setup='{"example_option":true}' >
        <source src="blue.mp4" type='video/mp4' ng-controller="vidCtrl as vc" ng-model="started"/>

        </video>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    var video = videojs('myVideo');
    var timeCheck=function(){
    var currT=Math.floor(video.currentTime());

    if ((currT===7||currT===14||currT===21 )&& currT!=0)
        {   

            video.pause();
            return true;

        }
    else {
        video.play();
        return false;
    }


};
```

`
for full code the pastebin links are
JavaScript:  http://pastebin.com/ruY5bhhG
HTML:        http://pastebin.com/sNxK2K4i

`

Comment: change your controller function from var timeCheck to this.timeCheck

Comment: Can you show us the complete controller code? Is the timeCheck function public? You should set the timeCheck function to the scope. Like `$scope.timeCheck = timeCheck`

Comment: use ng-if instead of ng-show . I guess ng-show not evaluate function,. It just work on Boolean value.

Comment: @ alsco77,Davide,Ved i tried all its not working

Comment: @ Ved this is the pastebin for javascript : http://pastebin.com/ruY5bhhG and for html :http://pastebin.com/sNxK2K4i

Comment: –  Ved plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/LAJx5ZhH9HNPcdjUEl30?p=catalogue

Comment: Ok.. I am looking it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work this way for the simple fact that nothing triggers the `timeCheck()` function for the time  intervals you want. You need to use a `$timeout` in your controller so it would run every 7 seconds, or every second, or whichever you want. When it runs, it will update a ***variable***, not a function, and you'll have:

```
<div id="ui1" ng-show="dc.timeCheck" >
    ...
</div>
```

For the `$timeout` part, you first need to inject `$timeout` to your controller and then when the controller initializes do:

```
$scope.checkTimeInterval = function () { 

     $scope.timeout = $timeout($scope.checkTimeInterval, 7000); //schedule the next run

     var result = //do your tests

     $scope.timeCheck = result; //this updates the variable that is binded to the ng-show
}

$scope.timeout = $timeout($scope.checkTimeInterval, 7000); //or any other time interval
```

Comment: @FossArduino On which line? Did you inject the `$timeout` service to the controller?

Comment: @OmriAharon videojs has a `timeupdate` event, so no need for `$timeout` ;)

Comment: @Omri yes i did do you want the pastebin link?

Comment: @FlorianGl Didn't know that, how does angular know to do a `$digest` process when it triggers?

Comment: @FossArduino You had `$scope.timeCheck=result;` outside of the function, and it didn't update. result should not be a function. You need to do `result = true` or `result = false` instead of returning true/false.

Comment: @FossArduino And your `ng-show` is still `dc.timeCheck()` instead of `dc.timeCheck`

Comment: @Omri still the same error check the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/LAJx5ZhH9HNPcdjUEl30?p=catalogue

Comment: @OmriAharon you can call `.$apply()` in the event handler function.

Comment: @FossArduino videoJs is not defined there.

Comment: @FossArduino I made several changes, since videojs is not defined I used a regular `new Date()` object, but on your project you'll use the video time. It doesn't check the seconds but the mechanism works. Take a look now: http://plnkr.co/edit/S23zmhuJxnA6okFhOSHI?p=preview

Comment: @FossArduino Open the console, wait 2 seconds, and then you'll see it writes 'false` every second. That shows you that the `timeCheck` updates every second, and that's what you wanted. Only thing is you need to adjust it to your project since in the plunker the `videojs` is not available.

Comment: @FossArduino If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so future seekers could know you found a solution to your problem.